# What is the meaning of "take the position" in this text?

Tags: expressions

> As Deepak Chopra's daughter, Mallika Chopra grew up with modern conveniences, new-age wisdom, and a lot of parental advice. But instead of taking the advice to settle down with a nice Indian guy, she moved across the world to follow her career dreams first. By following her heart, she ended up at the right place at the right time to meet the guy she was meant to end up with. Here, she tells her inspiring story.
>
> When I was 23, I moved from Boston to New Delhi for a dream job. I was launching MTV India, learning all aspects of media and sales, and I had a business card that could get me into any nightclub. But there was one caveat to **taking the position** : I had to move into my grandparents' home.

Is the expression **taking the position** simply mean **to go the mentioned nightclub? I mean is that an idiom?

Comment: Accepting the job offer.

Comment: But she had not being offred with a new job here. I know that one meaning.

Comment: "When I was 23, I moved from Boston to New Delhi *for a dream job*."

Answer (score 1):

> When I was 23, I moved from Boston to New Delhi for a **dream job**. I was launching MTV India, learning all aspects of media and sales, and I had a business card that could get me into any nightclub. But there was one caveat to taking **the position** : I had to move into my grandparents' home.

The *position* in question is *the job* mentioned at the beginning if the paragraph. If you *take a position*, you are *accepting a job offer*.

Comment: Had not she accepted the position? Cause she says : " I was launching ... "  ?

Comment: Yes, she accepted the position. But by accepting it, she also agreed to move in with her grandparents. That's why it is described as a "[caveat](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/caveat)": A condition that "is attached" to something.